# Opensearch C# client SSL connection bad_certificate

Tags: c#, opensearch

I am having difficulties in connecting Opensearch with C# client.
I used OpenSearch.Client and OpenSearch.Net and checked all their documents but I could not find any information on connecting C# client using SSL so I just followed the same way I used to connect to Elasticsearch and got below error.

```
[2023-06-07T09:48:46,493][WARN ][o.o.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [node-1] caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:50619}
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:499) ~[netty-codec-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:689) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:652) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) [netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) [netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482) ~[?:?]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:296) ~[netty-handler-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1343) ~[netty-handler-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236) ~[netty-handler-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285) ~[netty-handler-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529) ~[netty-codec-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468) ~[netty-codec-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    ... 16 more
```

I tried with root-ca.pem too but the result were the same. and those cert files were used in beats and logstash which work OK connecting to the same Opensearch server so I don't think the cert file is the issue.

Below is the test code that I used.

```
using OpenSearch.Client;
using OpenSearch.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;

var nodes = new Uri[]
{
    new Uri("https://localhost:9200")
};

var connectionPool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    .BasicAuthentication("admin", "admin")
    .PrettyJson()
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidations.AuthorityIsRoot(new X509Certificate("F:\\Developments\\OpenSearch\\DB\\config\\root-ca.pem")))
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidations.DenyAll);

OpenSearchClient osClient = new OpenSearchClient(settings);

var student = new Student { Id = 100, FirstName = "Paulo", LastName = "Santos"};

var response = osClient.Index(new IndexRequest<Student>(student, "students"));

if (!response.IsValid)
{
    // do something
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

and I also tried with below settings but got the same error so more likely that this is not an certificate file issue...

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
.BasicAuthentication("admin", "admin")
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidations.DenyAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow all certificate validation, it can be used:

```
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback((o, certificate, chain, errors) => true)
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidations.AllowAll);
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/working-with-certificates.html#_allowing_all_certificate_validation

This is not recommended in production.